# Hide android soft keyboard when click on navigation drawer in fragment

Tags: android

I want to hide soft keyboard when click on hamburger Icon in FragmentDrawer.I am using ActionBarDrawerToggle in Fragment. When I use Input Method Manager in onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed , it show error getSystemService and getCurrentFocus method cannot resolve.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "Id" of the Main Layout. and in the "OnClickListener" call the method pasted below.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if (activity != null) {
            if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity
                        .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                        .getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity to getCurrentFocus

```
      @Override
      public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {               
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS); 
        }
```